# RxJS and Unreachable Elements

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a scenario where given an observable, I would like to know of any elements that never reach any subscribers (ex. filtered out) and take action based on that. What would be the best approach to achieve something like this?

Comment: That absolutely depends on how deep you want the rabbit hole to go...

Answer (score 0):

### Option # 1

Use a combination of publish and function composition.

```
var Rx        = require('rx')
    log       = console.log.bind(console),
    source    = Rx.Observable.interval(100).take(100);
    published = source.publish(),
    accepted  = published.where(condition),
    rejected  = published.where(not(condition));

accepted.subscribe(log.bind(undefined, 'accepted: '));
rejected.subscribe(log.bind(undefined, 'rejected: '));

published.connect();

function condition (x) {
  return x % 4 === 0;
}

function not (func) {
  return function () {
    return !func.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

### Option # 2

Tag (mutate) the events and filter at the last second.

```
var Rx        = require('rx')
    log       = console.log.bind(console),
    source    = Rx.Observable.interval(100).take(100);

source
  .map(toAcceptable)
  .doAction(function (x) {
    x.acceptable = x.acceptable && condition1(x.value);
  })
  .doAction(function (x) {
    x.acceptable = x.acceptable && condition2(x.value);
  })
  .doAction(function (x) {
    log(x.acceptable ? 'accepted:' : 'rejected:', x);
  })
  .subscribe();

function condition1 (x) {
  return x % 4 === 0;
}

function condition2 (x) {
  return x % 3 === 0;
}

function toAcceptable (x) {
  return {
    acceptable: true,
    value: x
  };
}
```